# Why is clientWidth equal to 0?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner, writing a website and trying to add an image carousel into my homepage. I have 6 images displayed on screen next to each other. What I'm trying to do is move my images 1 to the left when the website is loaded so that slide1 is the first one to be displayed. Here is part of my index.html:

```
    <div class="cover-art-carousel">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="./covers/slide6.jpg" id="lastClone">
            <img src="./covers/slide1.png">
            <img src="./covers/slide2.png">
            <img src="./covers/slide3.jpg">
            <img src="./covers/slide4.jpg">
            <img src="./covers/slide5.jpg">
            <img src="./covers/slide6.jpg">
            <img src="./covers/slide1.png" id="firstClone">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
    <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>`
```

And this is my js:

```
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide img');

//Buttons
const prevButton = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');

//Counter
let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
```

When I load the site, clientWidth is equal to 0 even though I know it should be 300. The weirdest thing is that if I add an alert into my JS, it works fine. I'm sure I'm missing something super obvious but if anyone could help that would be great. Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: do you mean that the javascript is ignored and never runs, or it is ignored until the page finishes loading, then runs?

Comment: It probably ran but didn't change anything, did you check the value of your variables?

Comment: @Kira sorry, the javascript runs, but nothing changes and the images don't move.  The only way I can get them to move is if there is an alert somewhere in my js, which I don't want

Comment: Are you using `prevButton` and `nextButton` somewhere? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** tab which you can use to check if the CSS is applied to the elements. If it is, the issue is your CSS, not your JS. Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Comment: @ChrisLi The problem seems to be with the 'size' variable.  The value does not seem to change unless I have an alert in my script for some strange reason.

Comment: @DanteSuarez What do you mean _“The value does not seem to change”_? If you check which CSS rules are applied to the elements, what do you see? Do you see what you expect?

Comment: in your js add console.log(carouselSlide) just before you declare size and let us know what you get back in the console.  It still seems that the issue might be the dom not being fully loaded.  How big are the images?

Comment: @DCR Upon reconsideration, you could be on the right track. Getting `clientWidth` requires some layouting to be done by the browser engine, so it’s a safer bet to do this after `DOMContentLoaded`, possilby after `load`. This would also explain why it works with an `alert`: alerts pause JS execution, but maybe not the layouting, so the browser has plenty of time to determine the right value of `clientWidth`. For images also see [`naturalWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth) and the `loadstart` event which makes dimensions available.

Comment: @DCR <div class="slide" style="transform: translateX(0px);">
app.js:13:9.  The images are large (between 1400x1400 and 2286x2286)

Comment: @DanteSuarez Okay, now you can phrase a smart question: not _“why is my JS ignored by my browser”_ (it isn’t), but _“why is `clientWidth` equal to `0`”_. Googling this gives you some hints, but do consider using `naturalWidth` instead. You’ll still need to wait for the images to begin loading.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your js script like this:

```
window.onload = function(){ the rest of your js.....
```

}

it would seem that you may be trying to get the width before the images are loaded in.

Comment: _“it would seem that you may be trying to execute the js before the dom is loaded”_ — On what basis does it seem like that? `<script src="app.js"></script>` is below the relevant HTML. Also, why wait for every resource to be loaded? Why not `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){` … `});` or the `defer` attribute?

Comment: FROM OP: When I load the site, my Javascript is ignored by the browser. The weirdest thing is that if I add an alert into my JS, the thing works fine. I'm sure I'm missing something super obvious but if anyone could help that would be great. Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in my other comment, this could be the solution to the problem, but the reasoning is wrong. Either way, I can’t undo my downvote, but if the correct reason (`clientWidth` being `0` without everything being loaded) was edited in, I could upvote this answer.

Comment: @user4642212 If the images aren't loaded do you consider the dom loaded?

Comment: Those are separate steps. The DOM is guaranteed to finish loading before a page is “loaded” (with all external resources).

Comment: I just confirmed: first an image’s `loadstart` event is fired, then `DOMContentLoaded`, then the `load` of the image, then `load` of the entire page. On the `<img>`’s `load` event, the `naturalWidth`, `naturalHeight`, `clientWidth`, and `clientHeight` can be determined.